# ArcGIS Pro Dynamic Text Project Path abbreviation

Tags: arcgis-pro, dynamic-text

I am using Arcgis Pro and have saved a template for a map which uses the default 'Project Path'  dynamic text option to display the folder the location of the project. The problem is some of the file paths being used in this template are exceedingly long and difficult to display.

Is there any option to abbreviate the file path in dynamic text to only show the last two or three components?

I.e. Instead of showing

Path C:\FolderA\ProjectB\OfficerC\Working\IndustryD\Analysis\Map.aprx

just show:
\IndustryD\Analysis\Map.aprx

Comment: What is the formatting syntax currently in that dynamic text element?  Any options for modifying how it is displayed should be documented.  If there is not one for what you need, using pseudo-dynamic text may be an option but it will depend what you have wrapped around that text element.

Comment: Current text syntax is: Path <dyn type="project" property="path"/>

Comment: I suspect that it is this `Path <dyn type="project" property="path"/>` (I surrounded it with backticks).

Comment: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/add-and-modify-dynamic-text.htm describes lots of formatting options for some of the other tags but not for Path that I can see.  For pseudo-dynamic text you would need to be manipulating your layouts with ArcPy.